# Run GUI program on remote machine via python subprocess ssh

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssh, subprocess, xserver

Running RPi4s with Ubuntu Server 19.10, Python 3.7.5, `python3-xlib==0.15` and `pyautogui==0.9.50`. Everything is run as the default `ubuntu` user.

I'm trying to have `Machine A` send an ssh command to `Machine B` to run a GUI program and do some processing. I'm getting some `XAUTHORITY` errors.

Note: I don't want to see the GUI on `Machine A`s monitor - but the app running on `Machine B` needs a GUI.

So on `Machine A` I run:

```
subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'ubuntu@ip_of_machine_B', 'python3', '/path/to/my_script.py'])
```

On `Machine B`, `my_script.py` executes

```
subprocess.call(['python3', '/path/to/gui_script.py'])
```

Finally, `gui_script.py` attempts to

```
import os
os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'
os.environ['XAUTHORITY'] = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
import subprocess
import pyautogui


subprocess.Popen(['the_gui_app'])
# Do stuff with pyautogui and the app.
```

Unfortunately, `gui_script.py` is throwing the following

```
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0": No protocol specified.
```

I also tried setting the environment in the `subprocess` call in `my_script.py` via

```
my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env['DISPLAY'] = ':0'
my_env['XAUTHORITY'] = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
subprocess.call(['python3', '/path/to/gui_script.py'], env=my_env)
```

But that also failed.

My best guess is I need to change some setting somewhere on `Machine B` prior to running the workflow (ie, a one-time edit to `xauth`)? This is a closed system so security isn't an issue!

Comment: I found the answer...`DISPLAY` was set to `:1`. I assumed that it would be `:0` from all the examples I googled...so I changed the environment setting to be `:1` and it worked. Good for unix novices though...I had no idea it could be set to something else. I feel silly now... Not sure if I should answer the question or vote to close it.